# CSS for one column of images instead of two in Grid Plus

Tags: css, wordpress

http://maxvision.co.jp/

I am using a plugin called Grid Plus and as seen on the homepage, there are 3 columns. On other pages, I want to use Grid Plus for images but with one column, which isn't an option in the plugin settings. Is there any CSS I could use to make it one column?

Comment: Do you mean that homepage image doesn't use full width ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they are probably using some kind of grid system much like https://isotope.metafizzy.co/ or one of the others like it.

You should be able to override the width class on that particular page. Like this page you linked is home so it has a body class of .home or .page-id-2115 the other pages will have similar body classes.

```
.grid-stack.grid-stack-2>.grid-stack-item, .grid-stack.grid-stack-2>.grid-stack-item[data-gs-min-width='1'] {
    min-width: 100% !important;
}
```

or

```
.grid-stack.grid-stack-2>.grid-stack-item[data-gs-width='1']  {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

You might have to take a look at the grid you are building on the page you want to use this on. But the way I explained it earlier of using the body class of page-id-5275 and the above classes should work. You may have to use both in conjunction to override the existing css. But you should be able to add that in your childs css file and it should work. Without access I can't really tell but from my experience with these types of plugins it uses the css to set its width then calculates height for the grid based off what the CSS tells it.

Comment: I tried that CSS but it came back red and wouldn't work.

For example, this is a page that has 2 columns but want one.
http://maxvision.co.jp/index.php/okinawa-studio-1/

There is a CSS option within the plugin for each grid. Is there CSS that could be put inside there?

Comment: Updated answer above.

Comment: I just edited and added the 2nd class which I had earlier in my chrome tools and it increased the width to 100% it didn't refresh the grid but yeah... It should do that like I explained above by using the width from css and the height after that to set the grid.

Comment: The CSS isn't working in the plugin CSS section or page CSS section. I am not very knowledgable about coding so don't want to touch the editor...

Answer (score 0):

One more thing you might try is this. If you make your browser width mobile size it has another class that is defined

```
.grid-stack.grid-stack-one-column-mode>.grid-stack-item {
    position: relative!important;
    width: auto!important;
    left: 0!important;
    top: auto!important;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    max-width: none!important;
}
```

you might try that css with the above classes and see if you get some results. It adds that class when it is small enough via JavaScript. So it won't work with this class but that css might work inside the classes I posted above.

Comment: Is this for the css section inside the plugin? What do you mean by inside the above classes?